# Linux Mint randomly freezes

Tags: linux-mint, laptop, freeze, acer

It happens that every once in a while my notebook randomly freezes and I have to restart it.

I'm running Linux Mint 18.1 on my Acer Aspire ES1-311-P59G laptop.

How can I investigate this problem (i.e. what logs to revise and where are they located)?

Comment: Can you add more details? The lack of information here is likely why someone downvoted your post.

Comment: I don't really have much more information. I copied the last logs before the last freeze.
I cannot controle anything when it happens, not the keyboard, or the function keys, not even the mouse pointer. The only thing I can do is force power.
As the title says it happens randomly, sometimes I have Chrome open, sometimes the terminal, sometimes watching a movie.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and find out what is freezing.

When it freezes, try Ctrl-Alt-Backspace. If it's just the GUI that's frozen, that'll log you out and take you to a console, where you can view the logs.

The system log files are in /var/log/. However, starting with Mint 18 there is the `journalctl` command. [Here is some info](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=223066) that will get you started.

When you press Caps Lock a few times , does the corresponding indicator light go on and off?

Comment: I can't see the indicator light of caps lock because I have none.
I'll wait for Linux to freezes to test what you say, in the meanwhile the last logs I see from the last time it freezed are:
Apr 16 13:23:30 gabriel-ntb ntpd[5741]: Listen normally on 7 wls2 [2800:810:4b3:89e4:4901:1c02:d5ea:a86d]:123
Apr 16 13:23:30 gabriel-ntb ntpd[5741]: Listen normally on 8 wls2 [2800:810:4b3:89e4:28cf:8fe9:af81:a37b]:123
Apr 16 13:23:30 gabriel-ntb ntpd[5741]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Apr 16 13:23:32 gabriel-ntb ntpd[5741]: Soliciting pool server 2001:67c:1560:8003::c8